# How to send the element object as parameter to javascript function without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, href

In function ClickedRow, i want to use the "a" which is being clicked. So i want to receive it as a parameter.

```
<td ...... >
<span class="......>
  <span onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true">
      <a class="GridLinkRenderer" href="javascript:ClickedRow(this)"  onclicklink="javascript:ClickedRow(this)" urlText="XXXX">

<td ......
<span class="......>
  <span onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true">
      <a class="GridLinkRenderer" href="javascript:ClickedRow(this)"  onclicklink="javascript:ClickedRow(this)" urlText="XXXXX">
```

Based on clicked `<a ....>` I would like to hide/show it (or to show/hide next `<a class= "GridLinkRenderer"` in other `<td ...>`)   by function ClickedRow(this).
How can I do it ?

I've tried to send the clicked $(row).next().eq(0).tagName and `row.style.display = 'none'` , it says that it is "undefined".

```
function ClickedRow(row){

$(row).next().eq(0).hide();
$(row).hide();


}
```

Comment: If `ClickedRow` is called as an event handler, `this` should be the clicked row.

Comment: the vendor provided its own attribute "onclicklink" so probably it is not like "onclick" :( therefore this doesnt work ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, remove href and use

```
$('#TheidOfTheA').on('click'function(){
let myAElement = $(this);
}
```

Comment: I see, but unfortunately all html code is coming from vendor and it is not possible to change it. I could only tell the "javascript:ClickedRow(this):

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at closest(),find() and next() ?

- https://api.jquery.com/closest/
- https://api.jquery.com/next/
- https://api.jquery.com/find/

  $(row).closest('td').next('td').find('.GridLinkRenderer')

haven't tested this.. but if I'm thinking right this should be at least the point to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell by OP if the td are being used in a tr and the tr in a table as it should so I'll just mention real quick that it's invalid HTML should there be any td without a tr as a parent and it's invalid HTML having a tr without a table as its ancestor.

If starting at a tag nested within a td you'll need to *climb out*:

```
$(this).closest('td')...
```

Once at the cell level look around for the cells to the left: `....prev('td')`, or to the right: `....next('td')` or both: `....siblings('td')`. Then *go down* each td and find the link nested within and turn it off/on: `....find('.gLR').fadeToggle();`

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('.gLR').fadeToggle();
```

```js
$('.gLR').not('.g5').hide();

$('.gLR').on('click', function(e) {

  if ($(this).hasClass('g5')) {
    $('.gDir').fadeToggle();
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('g1') || $(this).hasClass('g9')) {
    const cell = $(this).closest('td');
    cell.siblings('td').find('.gLR').fadeToggle();
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('g4')) {
    $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('.gLR').fadeToggle();
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('g6')) {
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.gLR').fadeToggle();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 700 5vw/1.5 Consolas
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 10vh;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: cyan;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

a.g5:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}

a.g5:hover::after {
  content: '\1f536';
  font-size: 5vw;
}

td b {
  display: block;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='gRA'>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <b><a href='#/' class="gLR g0"></a></b>
    </td>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR gDir g1">⮝</a></b></td>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <b><a href='#/' class="gLR g2"></a></b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='gRB'>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR g3"></a></b></td>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR gDir g4">⮜</a></b></td>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR g5"></a></b></td>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR gDir g6">⮞</a></b></td>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR g7"></a></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='gRC'>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <b><a href='#/' class="gLR g8"></a></b>
    </td>
    <td><b><a href='#/' class="gLR gDir g9">⮟</a></b></td>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <b><a href='#/' class="gLR g10"></a></b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both recommendations(thx for it) - no success.
It looks that the "this" argument is not passed like clicked element(object) reference.

The parameter "row" seems to be like parent of all object, so like new Object and not the clicked object.

I am not sure if `href="javascript:ClickedRow(this)"  onclicklink="javascript:ClickedRow(this)"`  is correct syntax though.

Comment: `$('.gLR').on('click', ...` works if the class `.gLR` is the `<a class='.gLR'>` Is your `<td>` wrapped in a `<tr>` and the `<tr>` wrapped in a `<table>`? Invalid HTML may not be properly recognized or the results can be unpredictable.

Comment: BTW `"javascript:ClickedRow(this)"  onclicklink="javascript:ClickedRow(this)" urlText="XXXX"` should be removed it'll hinder jQuery. on-event attributes are never needed if using jQuery and if it actually worked and the href value did as well then you'll have 3 clicks for every user click. Remove the spans as well unless you need them to format the text outside of `<a>` or at least remove `onmousedown="event.cancelBubble = true"` which is useless if the callback has `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`

Answer (score 0):

> so copied Your sample and came up with this. ;)  try this out.. and
>   make sure You understand what's happening here.

```
$(() => {
            $("body").on("click",".GridLinkRenderer", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                //works on the first link.. stil misses a few check.. 
                //for example do we have the next td.. at all.. 
                console.log($(e.currentTarget).closest('td').next('td').find('.GridLinkRenderer'));
            })
        });
```